# How to find sockets on other Nodejs server instances?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, socket.io, fastify

My server is set up so that once a socket connects, it stores that id of that socket and associates it with a user in a map like so:

```
. . .

const socketTracker = new Map();

io.on('connect', async (socket) => {
    const userId = socket.handshake.query.userId;
    socketTracker.set(userId, socket.id);
    . . .

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        socketTracker.delete(userId);
    });

    . . .
});
. . .
```

A typical use case for my app is when a source user emits to the server a payload, along with a target user ID. The server then proceeds to find the associated socket ID of the target user (if there is one/if the target user is even online):

```
. . .
socket.on('some_event', async () => {
. . .
    const targetUserSocketId = socketTracker.get(targetUserId);
    if (targetUserSocketId) {
        const targetSocket = io.sockets.sockets.get(targetUserSocketId);
        targetSocket.emit('received_some_event', {});
    }
. . .
});
. . .
```

This works as expected as is, however this only works locally and when I only have one instance of my server running.

When deploying to the cloud, I have load balancing configured via Nginx for 4 instances. In other words, I would have 4 different `socketTracker` maps, each map having no knowledge of any existence of the others.

I'm using Postgres as my database and found [postgres-adapter](https://socket.io/docs/v4/postgres-adapter/), which at first glance seemed to be the solution to my problem. However after looking into it further, I hit a roadblock because I'm not exactly sure how a source user with a connection to a server instance on port, say, 5000, would be able to successfully relay a payload to a target user that is sitting on a server instance on port 5001.

In other words, the server instance on port 5000 would have the following map:

```
{
    sourceUserId: 'sourceUserSocketId'
}
```

and the server instance on port 5001 would have,

```
{
    targetUserId: 'targetUserSocketId'
}
```

And then if the source user decides to send a message to the target user, then:

```
const targetUserSocketId = socketTracker.get(targetUserId); // <-- will always be `undefined`
```

Am I missing a crucial component here with `postgres-adapter`? Perhaps my approach with `socketTracker` is unnecessary?

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual solution to something like this involves using a piece of software the centrally keeps track of where all users are connected.  Once such piece of software is the [socket.io redis adapter](https://socket.io/docs/v4/redis-adapter/) and it keeps track of all connected users in a central redis database.  It also hooks into socket.io so you can virtually access all users no matter which server they are connected to.

So, if code on ServerA does a something like `io.to("room1").emit()`, it will find all connected users in that room across all servers and make sure they are notified properly from the server that they are connected to.

So, rather than keep your local Map on each server in memory (which is only accessible to just that server), that data would be combined for all users in a centrally accessible database that all your server instances can query.  Then, when code on ServerA needs to communicate with a user who is currently connected to ServerC, ServerA can send ServerC a message to tell it what it should send to this other user.

You can either write something like this yourself expressly for your purpose or use an existing package already designed to do this.

Comment: Yup, I've seen the redis adapter, however if I were to use an adapter, I'd use the Postgres one (as I've indicated in the OP), because installing additional libraries like redis is unnecessary. My question however isn't about `io.to("room1").emit()` as they have in the docs, I specifically need to find a target socket as in the example in the OP, how can I do this? I can't find it anywhere in the documentation

Comment: This part from your answer is what I'm looking for: `So, rather than keep your local Map on each server in memory [...] that data would be combined for all users in a centrally accessible database`. I've installed the Postgres adapter, I've set it up upon instantiation, now what? How do I find target socket ID (which I'll need in order to find the target socket itself) on server B when a source user sends a socket message to server A?

Comment: @MikeK - With a supporting adapter, you would use `io.to(someSocketId).emit()`.  You cannot "get" a socket from another server and use it on your server.  That simply cannot be done as sockets are local to a specific server.   What the redis adapter does (same thing could be done with Postgres) is to keep track in a database of which server host each user is currently connected to and then all servers can look that up, find out which host a user is one, then message that host using some communication channel between hosts what info you want sent to that user.

Comment: @MikeK - The recipient host then looks up that user to find its actual `socket` object and sends the message to that user.